# swift package manager link dynamic lib

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, swift-package-manager

i used swift on linux, made the Package.swift file including some libraries, but when i built the project with swift build command, the libraries were static linked with the executable file. i tried to generated a Xcode project used the `swift package generate-xcodeproj` command, built the project in Xcode, then opened the Product directory, i found that the libraries were dynamic linked with the executable file, what did the Xcode doing? and how can i build it as a dynamic link use `swift build` command, could you help me

Answer (score 1):

SwiftPM version 3 was only able to build executables with statically linked libraries. In SwiftPM version 4 (currently in beta, will be released this fall) you can also build with dynamically linked libraries. See [SE-0146](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0146-package-manager-product-definitions.md) for more information.